# When does subject header in Mime message gets encoded?

Tags: encoding, mime

I am trying to understand the mime encoding. I have 2 instance of message with subject header :

1) Reply to Comment in `Is my stone dead? Constantly quick-flashing white side-LED =?=` in ICS Webtop Update = useless lapdock?

2)Reply to Comment in `Is? white side-LED =?=` in ICS Webtop Update = useless lapdock

I see different behavior in both the cases, while the former is getting encoded the later is not. Having read through some of Mime documentation, I understand the theory that when there isn't a 7bit non-ASCII character clients may encode the message. But why is the difference in above messages ? Is message length a factor too ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The subject line doesn't have anything to do with whether the body needs to be encoded.

Comment: Like I have mentioned it is Subject Header and not body where I am see this issue.

Comment: I think you edited your question title after I posted my comment. Anyway, I've seen different subject encodings depending on the mail client being used.